# What's the use case for params.require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't really understand the purpose of `params.require` - more specifically, what the use is for it to raise an exception when a param is missing.

I know I might want some params to be present for a given request, but why would I want to return a 500 server error if any of them are missing? Why wouldn't I traverse params for the parameters I want using conditional logic and return `flash[:error]` instead?

Comment: the idea is that you use `params.require`, then you could handle the error https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#handling-of-unpermitted-keys

Comment: the option you are mentioning is also valid, but at first sight it seems that params.require could produce a shorter code... maybe

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Rails using Strong Parameters, see [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). Ive pasted the section on Strong Parameters at the bottom of the answer

Unlike other platforms that whitelist everything and require blacklisting of parameters, Rails does the opposite. Everything is blacklisted and you are required to whitelist the parameters you wish to allow through mass assignment.

Hence why if you try to save an object and haven't permitted a certain param, you will see a "Unpermitted parameters:" in your log/console.

Its a best practice to perform save/update actions through requiring and whitelisting params you wish to permit.

**Strong Parameters**

With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted. This means you'll have to make a conscious choice about which attributes to allow for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.

In addition, parameters can be marked as required and flow through a predefined raise/rescue flow to end up as a 400 Bad Request with no effort.

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # This will raise an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception
  # because it's using mass assignment without an explicit permit
  # step.
  def create
    Person.create(params[:person])
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key
  # in the parameters, otherwise it'll raise a
  # ActionController::ParameterMissing exception, which will get
  # caught by ActionController::Base and turned into that 400 Bad
  # Request reply.
  def update
    person = current_account.people.find(params[:id])
    person.update!(person_params)
    redirect_to person
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters
    # is just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same
    # permit list between create and update. Also, you can specialize
    # this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```